# Asp.net Custom Server Control: When and how to retrieve value of hidden field to feed property?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to develop a Custom ASP.Net Server Control, which can be manipulated at the client. To save the changes after a Postback there is a hidden field. On the OnLoad event I retrieve the value to write the Property, but it seems too late, because the controls are already built. I know I could manipulate the controls on the PreRender event, but to me it seems there is a better way to handle this. Anyone an idea?

```
public class Control : CompositeControl {

  private bool mProperty;
  private HiddenField hiddenField;


  public virtual bool Property {
    get {
      return mProperty;
    }
    set {
      mProperty = value;
    }
  }
  protected override void CreateChildControls() {
    Controls.Clear();
    CreateControlHierarchy();
    ClearChildViewState();
  }
  protected virtual void CreateControlHierarchy() {
    CreateHiddenField();
    CreateContent();
  }

  protected virtual void CreateHiddenField() {
    hiddenField = new HiddenField();
    hiddenField.ID = "hiddenField";
    hiddenField.Value = Property.ToString().ToLower();
    Controls.Add(hiddenField);
  }  
  protected virtual void CreateContent() {
    contentPanel = new Panel();
    contentPanel.ID = "content";
    contentPanel.Vsiible = Property;
    Controls.Add(contentPanel);
  }
  protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnLoad(e);
    if(Page.IsPostback) {
      Property = Convert.ToBoolean(Page.Request.Form[hiddenField.UniqueId]);
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit Possible Solution:**

I got rid of the OnLoad event and edited the property like so:

```
public virtual bool Property { 
  get { 
    if (Page.IsPostBack) {
      EnsureChildControls();
      return Convert.ToBoolean(Page.Request.Form[hiddenField.UniqueID]);
    }
    return mProperty; 
  }
  set { 
    mProperty = value;
  }
}
```

Is that a good approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved what I wanted to do, by implementing a ValueChanged EventHandler for the hidden field and edit the setter of the property to take care of all dependencies.

```
public class Control : CompositeControl {

  private bool mProperty;
  private HiddenField hiddenField;


  public virtual bool Property {
    get {
      return mProperty;
    }
    set {
      mProperty = value;
      if (contentPanel != null) contentPanel.Visible = value;
      if (hiddenField != null && hiddenField.Value != value.ToString().ToLower()) hiddenField.Value = value.ToString().ToLower();
    }
  }
  protected override void CreateChildControls() {
    Controls.Clear();
    CreateControlHierarchy();
    ClearChildViewState();
  }
  protected virtual void CreateControlHierarchy() {
    CreateHiddenField();
    CreateContent();
  }

  protected virtual void CreateHiddenField() {
    hiddenField = new HiddenField();
    hiddenField.ID = "hiddenField";
    hiddenField.Value = Property.ToString().ToLower();
    hiddenField.ValueChanged += hiddenField_ValueChanged;
    Controls.Add(hiddenField);
  }  
  protected virtual void CreateContent() {
    contentPanel = new Panel();
    contentPanel.ID = "content";
    contentPanel.Vsiible = Property;
    Controls.Add(contentPanel);
  }
  void hiddenField_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Property = Convert.ToBoolean(hiddenField.Value);
  }
  protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
    EnsureChildControls();
    base.OnInit(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion is to set the post back value both on Property and on control, because the property is used only when the control is created.

```
 protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnLoad(e);
    if(Page.IsPostback) {
      if(hiddenField != null)
         hiddenField.Value = Page.Request.Form[hiddenField.UniqueId].ToString();

      Property = Convert.ToBoolean(Page.Request.Form[hiddenField.UniqueId].ToString());    
    }
  }
```

Comment: The problem with that was that the Panel Control already used the Property to set its Visibility.

Comment: I edited my question with a viable solution, what do you think about that?

Comment: @daniatic yes, I just go and type the same, but now I see that you have all ready write it, so I remove it. This work, only if the UniqueID have all ready been set.

Comment: EnsureChildControls() keeps an eye on that!

Comment: May I ask how one might change this value client side in javascript? I am not seeing anything called "hiddenField" when my markup is rendered.

Comment: @RandyWhirl In this question the user (see the question) is create dynamically this `hiddenField` on this function `CreateHiddenField()`